# Generate a URL with segments using CreatedAtRouteResult in ASP.NET Core with endpoint routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

If I understand things correctly, in ASP.NET Core 3, one is supposed to use [endpoint routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1). For that reason, I've written a `Startup` class like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
    }
}
```

I'd now like to make a REST resource with a `Post` and a `Get` method, like this:

```
[ApiController, Route("[controller]")]
public class FooController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post(Foo foo)
    {
        return new CreatedAtRouteResult(new { id = foo.Id }, foo);
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult Get(string id)
    {
        return new OkObjectResult(new Foo { Id = id });
    }
}
```

I can `GET` a resource using what I'd consider the canonical URL for the resource:

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:52268/foo/bar
*   Trying ::1:52268...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 52268 (#0)
> GET /foo/bar HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:52268
> User-Agent: curl/7.67.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Tue, 12 May 2020 15:25:12 GMT
<
{"id":"bar"}* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Cool, that works. Let's try to `POST` a representation:

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:52268/foo -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"id\": \"bar\" }"
*   Trying ::1:52268...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 52268 (#0)
> POST /foo HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:52268
> User-Agent: curl/7.67.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 15
>
* upload completely sent off: 15 out of 15 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Location: http://localhost:52268/Foo?id=bar
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Tue, 12 May 2020 15:25:53 GMT
<
{"id":"bar"}* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Notice the `Location` header. It's `http://localhost:52268/Foo?id=bar`, not `http://localhost:52268/foo/bar`. The `id` is formatted as a query string parameter, not a URL segment.

How do I make the generated URL `http://localhost:52268/foo/bar`?

(Ignore the casing problem. If you can tell me how to arrive at `http://localhost:52268/Foo/bar` that'll count as an answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`CreatedAtAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.createdataction?view=aspnetcore-3.1), which is available if your controller class derives from `Controller` or `ControllerBase`:

```
return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), new { foo.Id }, foo);
```

or try named routes like

```
return new CreatedAtRouteResult(nameof(Get), new { id = foo.Id }, foo);
```

then change attribute for `Get` to

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = nameof(Get))]
public ActionResult Get(string id)
{
    return new OkObjectResult(new Foo { Id = id });
}
```